# do i have to login github account every time i clone or pull a repository in pythonanywhere?

Tags: git, pythonanywhere

I am using Pycharm, Github and pythonanywhere.

Every time I want to **clone** or **pull** a repository in **pythonanywhere bash console**
with **git**, an authentication procedure show up and I have to fill it out again and that slow down my performance.

**are there a way to do an automatic credential login in pythonanywhere?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

- cache your git credentials using `git config credential.helper cache --timeout n`
- store your credentials permanently using `git config credential.helper store`.

To make these changes globally, call `git config` with the `--global` tag.

[Also see the manual on credential storage for reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

Comment: thanks for everything! Now that I understood the local a global concepts with **Git** I can improve my performance.